precise Box projection into the future
I'm designing simple forecasting box where I can position one corner in the past and another in the future date and price. It currently works well allowing me reposition the corners of the box with the mouse except it does not let me move into the future. It stops at the last candle.  I need precise control so indefinite extend will not work.    Box shown stops at last bar
Thanks in advance
I'm expecting to move my box freely on the screen including into the future date. It does not do it

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
